# jQuery Dropdown Filter Returns only one result

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a table that displays event information. One of the columns is "State" showing what State the event is being held in. I want my dropdown list of states to filter only the matching states in the table. The current code I have does this but it only returns the last matching state. I want my jQuery filter to return all the matching states. For example, if there are two events in my table happening in Texas - if I select Texas in the dropdown only one of the events is returned. How do I get it to show me both Texas events? I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

My code
I have a typical State Dropdown html with all states but here's a quick example without every state:

```js
$("#filter").change(function() {
  // console.clear();
  var filterValue = $(this).val();
  var row = $('.row-conventions');
  console.log(filterValue);

  row.each(function(i, el) {
    if ($(el).attr('data-type') == filterValue) {
      row.hide();
      $(el).show();
    }
  });

  if ("all" == filterValue) {
    row.show();
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Select Your State:</label>
<select class="state" id="filter">
  <option value="all" selected="selected">Select a State</option>
  <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
  <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
</select>
```

I attempted to update .each to .map but that didn't work.

Comment: Comment-answers flagged for deletion. Please post proper answers so the question can be resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("#filter").change(function() {
            // console.clear();
            var filterValue = $(this).val();
            var row = $('.row-conventions');
            console.log(filterValue);
           
            row.hide();
            row.each(function(i, el) {
              if ($(el).attr('data-type') == filterValue) {
                $(el).show();
              }
            });

            if ("all" == filterValue) {
                row.show();
              }

            });
```

I just needed to move row.hide() outside of the function.